# Simple exo player keep playing video audio when mediasource changed

Tags: java, android-studio, exoplayer

I'm sorry for my bad english.  I'm using Exoplayer for streaming video, but when I change the video resource, it keeps playing the old video and audio. I already stopped the video, but it's not working.  Here is the code:

```
 private void videoStop() {
    url.clear();
    resumePosition = 0;
    if (player != null && simpleExoPlayerView != null && simpleExoPlayerView.getPlayer() != null) {
            simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(null);
            player.stop(true);
            player.release();
            player = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to pause the player first like this

```
simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
```

Comment: i'm using exoplayer release version 2.8.2 and i've tried that but not successful

Comment: did you build the new resource and initialized the player again?